# Represent arithmetic expressions

Tags: haskell

I want to compute in Haskell an expressions that contains letters and operations.

I defined an algebraic type Expr a to represent arithmetic expressions:

```
data Expr a = Val a
    | Var [Char]
    | Sum (Expr a) (Expr a)
    | Prod (Expr a) (Expr a)
    | Minus (Expr a) (Expr a)
```

And the operation

```
compute :: Num a => [(Char], a)] -> Expr a -> a
```

But I don't know how to implement the function, I am new to haskell.

Comment: I would start by *trying* to implement the function. Nobody's going to write your code for you—please show an attempt.

Comment: Smells like homework :/

Comment: You should start by parsing your expression into `Expr` (which is essentially a binary tree). Then, given this `Expr` and a symbol table which maps symbols like `x` and `y` to their values, computing this expression will boil down to going through the binary tree and performing appropriate computations at each node.

Comment: can you explain in words what the `compute` function is supposed to do - in particular what its inputs represent? I'm having a hard time figuring this out from the type signature (even after mentally correcting the typo). [I will repeat what @AJFarmar said though, no-one is going to write the function for you if you show no attempt.]

Comment: `compute` already receives the symbol table and syntax tree; it just needs to evaluate the expression. E.g. `compute [("foo", 5)] (Sum (Var "foo") (Val 3))` should return 8.

Comment: ah, so the list of pairs is a mapping from variable names to values. That makes sense, but wasn't obvious (to me) without further explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Given a symbol table and a syntax tree, you need to evaluate the expression. For example,

```
> compute [("foo", 5)] (Sum (Var "foo") (Val 3))
8
```

because `foo + 3 == 5 + 3 == 8`.

In order to write this function, you simply need to handle each of the 5 type of expressions that `compute` could receive:

```
compute :: Num a => [([Char], a)] -> Expr a -> a
compute st (Val x) = x
compute st (Var v) = ...
compute st (Sum x y) = ...
compute st (Prod x y) = ...
compute st (Minus x y) = ...
```

I've filled in the most trivial case as an example. The computed value of a `Val` value is simply the value of type `a` it wraps: `compute [] (Val 3) == 3`.

For `Var`, you need to find `v` in the symbol table `st` and return its corresponding value. The predefined function `lookup` will be useful. For example, `compute [("foo", 5)] (Var "foo") == 5`. You'll have to decide what to do in a case like `compute [] (Var "foo")`, where `foo` is not defined. The function `maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b` may come in handy.

For `Sum`, `Prod`, and `Minus`, you need to recursively evaluate each operand, then add/subtract/multiply the results. For example, `compute st (Sum (Val 3) (Val 5)) == compute st (Val 3) + compute st (Val 5)`.